# WPF Settings Page; Hiding/Showing Controls; Best Practice

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In WPF, I am trying to create a settings page like the one in Visual Studio (Tools -> Options) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OA9X.png)

I realize the selection menu is a treeview but I am unsure how to hide/show the controls on the right.

What is the best and proper way of doing this in WPF?

Comment: You can put a ContentControl there and bind containers to it's content property.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to do this is to divide the page into 2 grid columns. In your first column, you can place the treeview. The second column will consist of the data page. You can bind the visibility of this grid column when there is a selection in the tree view using a converter or so or display a default view there.

You can handle the selection changed event of the treeview and bind the selecteditem to a property and as per the selecteditem you can change the view on the second column.

Hope this helps.